# Facing issues in Identify button in selenium

Tags: selenium, element, selenium-ide

I am working on 1 project, where i have to locate button, i have used xpath for same, but button id change on every refresh, so i am facing problem in it..
Below is screenshot for same - let me know you can i identify that button so that it will not cause error even if id chages

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen11" class=" x-btn-text">Login</button>
```

[image]

Code HTML

```
<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="LoginButton" style="float: left;"><table style="width: auto;" id="ext-comp-1032" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon x-btn-over x-btn-focus" cellspacing="0"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button class=" x-btn-text" id="ext-gen12" type="button">Login</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xPath:

```
//button[text()='Login']
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath should do the trick:

```
Command: clickAndWait
Target: //input[@value='Login']
```

**Edit**

Assuming, that there is only one button with value "Login" on it

Comment: wow ... Is the page publicly available? Because I can try it by myself with the IDE...

Comment: page is not available to public yet..Its on our own server.:(

Comment: Oh darn... At least I created little screenshot which might help. I do it on example of Wikipedia. The testmodel in IDE is: Open English Wiki, click on Login link and then on loggin button. Once Selenium IDE records the click on the button, you can change inside the IDE how the Login link will be located. If this does not work, I think that you will have to make your site accessible... Scrren: http://twio.cz/adys

Comment: This xPath can't work, because there is no input element with value equal to 'Login'. And there is no need to publish your site, rohit.